# Java Spring/Workflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have 50,000,000 files that need to be processed using 3-5 different filters configured in workflows

I plan to use microservice architecture

My Questions

1. i want to use spring integration and batch, to run the workflows. and design the workflows, do you agree or is there another java based system you recommend?
2. can spring batch can handle "long running i.e. days" workflows.
3. can spring batch/integration load xml files on the fly

Answer (score 0):

I think Spring Batch is pretty good for this job, below my answers.

1. I recommend you Spring Batch for this job. It's easy to use and in combination with Spring Workflow are good for the workflow desing.
2. Yes, it's really good. You need to configure it well.
3. I'm not sure what are you saying with on the fly. (batch files or configuration files). For batch files yes. For configuration files, it depends on how you load the configuration and how you will use the context.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Spring Batch can process files based on multiple filters. It can also be easily customized to fit most of your needs and has really fast processing speeds. However, I haven't tried it with anything close to 50,000,000 files, so can't vouch for that.

To run a Spring Batch application as a microservice, take a look at Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Task. Also, look into Spring Cloud Dataflow for orchestration.